# Binomial distribution for a list

Tags: fitting

I have the following list:

```
l = {2, 8, 24, 64, 138, 272, 492, 808, 1252, 1816, 2476, 3216, 3958, 
4640, 5200, 5560, 5684, 5560, 5200, 4640, 3958, 3216, 2476, 1816, 
1252, 808, 492, 272, 138, 64, 24, 8, 2};
```

when I list plot this I get a similar profile to binomial distribution.

[image]

How can I check what sort of a distribution this list is following?

Comment: How was this symmetric sequence generated?  It is certainly not a set of expectations from a binomial distribution (the spread is much wider than that of a binomial distribution).  One can see the the sum of the integers is 2^16 and the length of the list is 33 (suggesting that the corresponding numbers should be 0 to 32 rather than 1 to 33).  And the sequence is not in http://oeis.org.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Reverse[l] === l` holds, so `p = 1/2`.

One way to find $n$ is to test how proportional your list is to the probabilities of the outcomes in the center part (because `Reverse[l] === l`) of the support of a $\text{binom}(n,1/2)$-distribution.

The code below computes the proportionality factors for different values of $n$.
 The largest and the smallest factor for a given $n$ are compared on log-scale.

```
Table[{Length[l] + i - 1,
       Abs[Subtract @@ Log[l/PDF[BinomialDistribution[Length[l] + i - 1, 1/2],
                                  Range[i/2, i/2 + Length[l] - 1]] // MinMax // N]]},
      {i, 0, 40, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{32, 12.261976}, {34, 10.092057}, {36, 8.530821}, {38, 7.2959034}, {40, 6.2742521},  
>  {42, 5.4055631}, {44, 4.6528238}, {46, 3.9913072}, {48, 3.4035205}, {50, 2.8765655},  
>  {52, 2.4471472}, {54, 2.0780497}, {56, 1.7397901}, {58, 1.4509183}, {60, 1.2351549},  
>  {62, 1.0417418}, {64, 0.86137151}, {66, 0.69273006}, {68, 0.78465073}, {70, 0.90048255},  
>  {72, 1.0231556}}
> ```

The minimum (closest to proportionality) is at `n = 66`.